# Lirc, irxevent: Why doesn't it work with Nautilus?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, lirc

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity 3D and use a remote control via lirc. Everything works fine in applications like Firefox, Banshee, but when I focus Nautilus or Gedit any key which refers to "CurrentWindow" doesn't work, i. e. (from ~/.lircrc):

```
begin
    prog = irxevent
    button = KEY_OK
    config = Key Return CurrentWindow
end
```

I know that it worked on an older system, like 11.04. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I **workaround** I installed [xautomation](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xautomation)[image: Install xautomation] and modified *~/.lircrc* to use `xte` instead of `irxevent` wherever it referred to `CurrentWindow`. The mentioned passage now looks like this:

```
begin
    prog = irexec
    button = KEY_OK
    config = xte 'key Return'
end
```

Now everything's working fine again.